# Mongodb shell: Modifying each element in collection, with javascript logic

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to copy a field from one part of a document to another part of that document. The only way I can think of doing this is with actual javascript - though I'm open to doing it with straight up mongo querys.

I've already got this done in Javascript - not to bad - but I don't know how to do a `forEach` that actually gives me a document that is able to be saved.

For instance, all `doc`s below are not mongo documents, and cannot be modified and then saved, e.g. `doc.save()` or `doc.update()`

```js
myCol = db.getCollection('something').find({}).forEach((doc) => { 
doc.name = doc.name + doc.secondaryName
doc.update()
 })
```

Is there another way I can accomplish this? Is using a cursor just the wrong way?